# How to get VBA Function to store cell address values instead of values at these cell address

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I know this is a very unusual question, it will probably not make sense to you why I want to do this but...

This happens if the value in cell A1 is 5:

Myfunction(A1): outputs 5

In vba module:

```
Function Test(array As String)
   Test=array
End function
```

Examples of what I want:

Myfunction(A1): outputs string "A1"

Or

Myfunction(A1:B3): outputs string "A1:B3"

Or

Myfunction(A1:B3 & B5:B9): outputs string "A1:B3 & B5:B9"

How do I get the vba function to do this. Basically I want the function to store the cell address as a string and not the values located at the cell address locations. I know you can use "A1:A4" when you enter the values into the function or something along those lines but that's not what I'm looking for. Also this is for a function not a sub.

Comment: Neither of the first examples are very hard to answer, but "A1:B3 & B5:B9" is confusing? You are planning to delimit multiple ranges with "&"?

Comment: Yes so in my code I will use the split function to seperate the strings A1:A5 & B1:B5 into two seperate strings. The I will use the range functions to create arrays from there

Comment: Then the only way to do that is to use quotes to denote that it is a string.  But the better method would be to use a param array that is the range and then  iterate that with the ranges to load the arrays.

Comment: `Function MyFunction(ParamArray arr as range)`  Then you can enter `Myfunction(A1:B3,B5:B9)` iterate the ranges and load arrays from their values.

Comment: Scott, thanks I will research the ParamArray method more. I have already done some research. The thing is in my final function I will be having many arrays and inputs such as    MyFunction(D6&D7&D8, A1:A9&B1:B9&C1:C9, E1:E9, G1)

Comment: This is an xy problem.  without knowing exactly your plans we cannot help much, because what we suggest with the knowledge you have given would be incorrect.

Comment: Scott thanks for the feedback. If I know how to just input stuff like a1:a5 &b1:b5. into the function and get the code to store the text as "a1:a5 & b1&b5"   instead of storing the actual values in those arrays I would be good. There is a lot of remaining work in the code but with my ability it will be simple. Also the reason why I can not input into myfunction("a1:a5& b1&b5") the time it would take to add the quotes would be annoying. Maybe I can do something like this in vba.       ``` Function myfunction("array" As String) ```  I will have to check that though.

Comment: there is no way to do `a1:a5 & b1&b5` without the quotes,  just like you cannot pass a string without the quotes, you will not be able to pass ranges with `&`

Answer (score 1):

### ParamArray

[`Understanding parameter arrays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays)

- In `Excel`, to select a multiarea range, select the first range, then hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while selecting the next ranges.
- In `Excel` use e.g. `=RangeAddress(A1:A5,C3:C7,Z11:Z75)`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function RangeAddress( _
    ParamArray rg() As Variant) _
As String
    Dim arg As Variant
    If UBound(rg) = 0 Then
        RangeAddress = rg(0).Address(0, 0)
    Else
        Dim n As Long
        For Each arg In rg
            RangeAddress = RangeAddress & arg.Address(0, 0) & " & "
        Next arg
        RangeAddress = Left(RangeAddress, Len(RangeAddress) - 3)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can try something like this:

```
Function MyFunction(rng as range) as string
   MyFunction = cstr(rng.address)
end function
```

Go to your sheet, select any cell or cells.

In your immediate window, type: `?MyFunction(selection)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment unfortunately the range method will not work with a setup like (a1:a5 & b1:b5 & d1:d5)   with the column and row address being arbitrary and not actually what I put.